# Invoking hub method from signalr .net client throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr.client

I've been trying to call a method on my hub from a signalr .Net client however it throws the following exception:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s]
   System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s) +10894409
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonSerializerExtensions.Parse(JsonSerializer serializer, String json) +63
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubRequestParser.Parse(String data, JsonSerializer serializer) +19
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data) +40
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequest>b__7() +34
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func) +28
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.<ProcessSendRequest>d__10.MoveNext() +364
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +386
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +415
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

This is when I try to invoke the method on a remote host, the weird thing when developing it it actually does work locally...

Here is the code of the hub:

```
public void UpdateLocalPlayerName(string name)
{
    ...

    foreach (var connection in websiteConnections)
    {
        Clients.Client(connection.ConnectionID).UpdateLocalPlayerName(Context.ConnectionId, name);
    }
}
```

And here is how I try to invoke it with the .Net client

```
public void UpdateLocalPlayerName(string name)
{
    MainHubProxy.Invoke<string>("UpdateLocalPlayerName", name);
}
```

I am using 2.0.3.0 version of the .Net client and the server runs IIS8...

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Its possible the variable "name" you pass on the client side is Null

Comment: Pretty sure it isn't, as it works locally.

Comment: It's not your case, but I was facing same problem and in my case, the exception was caused by a redirection in the proxy server when connecting using HTTP. Switched to HTTPS and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be I had www. infront of the server's url I was connecting to, guess the routing prevented the arguments from being passed correctly. Changed the url to the url without www and it worked.